# A neater way to use Function delegate over Action delegate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, generics, delegates

I wish to iterate over a collection in a thread safe manner. I find it's convieniant to have one method called

```
/// <summary>
/// This visits all items and performs an action on them in a thread manner
/// </summary>
/// <param name="visitAction">The action to perform on the item</param>
public void VisitAllItems(Action<Item> visitAction) {
    lock (listLock) {
        foreach (Item item in this.ItemList) {
            visitAction.Invoke(item);
        }
    }
}
```

An example of it's use could be

```
/// <summary>
/// Saves each item in the list to the database
/// </summary>
protected static void SaveListToDatabase() {
    this.VisitAllItems(item => {
        bool itemSavedSuccessfully = item.SaveToDB();
        if(!itemSavedSuccessfully) {
            //log error message
        }
    });
}
```

Another example of it's use would be

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the number of special items in the list.
/// </summary>
protected int GetNumberOfUnsynchronisedItems() {
    int numberOfSpecialItems = 0;
    this.VisitAllItems((item) => {
        numberOfSpecialItems += item.IsItemSpecial() ? 1 : 0;
    });
    return numberOfSpecialItems;
}
```

But I'm sure there is a better way of writing the `VisitAllItems` method to use a `Func<>` rather than an `Action<>` delegate to return this value. I've tried several things but end up with compilation errors.

Can anyone see a neater way to implement this method?

Thanks,
Alasdair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the usage, so it's hard to tell what exactly would be useful for you. But one way would be to return one result for each item in the collection, and then use LINQ to combine the results.

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> VisitAllItems<TResult>(
    Func<Item, Result> visitfunction)
{
    var result = new List<TResult>();
    lock (listLock)
    {
        foreach (Item item in ItemList)
            result.Add(visitfunction(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Normally, I would use `yield return` instead of manually creating the `List<T>`, but I think it's better this way here, because of the `lock`.

The usage would be like this:

```
protected int GetNumberOfUnsynchronisedItems()
{
    return VisitAllItems(item => item.IsItemSpecial())
                  .Count(isSpecial => isSpecial);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both svick and @jonskeet. I understand both your explanations and both seem equally suitable given my situation. Unless I can be convinced otherwise I've given the points to you for no better reason than someone needs to challenge jon. cheers

Comment: You shouldn't decide based on the reputation score, but only on the answers themselves. Also, you can (and should) “give points” to more than one answer by upvoting them. And you should upvote all answers that you good or useful.

Comment: Fair point (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). But my accepted answer still stands. +1 to @JonSkeet as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could follow the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) model, but it wouldn't be *terribly* pleasant to use:

```
public TAccumulate VisitAllItems<TAccumulate>(TAccumulate seed,
    Func<Item, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> visitor) {
    TAccumulate current = seed;
    lock (listLock) {
        foreach (Item item in this.ItemList) {
            current = visitor(current, item);
        }
    } 
    return current;
}

...

protected int GetNumberOfUnsynchronisedItems() {
    return VisitAllItems(0, 
        (count, item) => count + item.IsItemSpecial() ? 1 : 0);
}
```

How many different aggregation functions do you actually need? For example, if *most* of the time you're just counting, you might want:

```
public void VisitAndCount<TAccumulate>(Func<Item, bool> visitor) {
    int count = 0;
    lock (listLock) {
        foreach (Item item in this.ItemList) {
            if (visitor(item)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

then:

```
protected int GetNumberOfUnsynchronisedItems() {
    return VisitAndCount(item => item.IsItemSpecial());
}
```